# OpenJPA schema configuration

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I am using OpenJPA 1.2.3 on WebSphere with DB2.
Is there a way to build and bundle my application in a way that allows for the same application (EAR) to have a changing Schema name based on environment (DEV, ACPT, PROD, etc).

My PU is setup up to be container managed as follows:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="My_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSource</jta-data-source>
            ...
            <properties>
                    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="MYSCHEMA"/>
                    <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
                    <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have looked into putting this in the ORM.xml, but this is still a static value for the schema, and does not externalize the setting; also, it doesn't seem to work (I have seen the many threads discussing this). I also, have looked into putting this configuration into the WebSphere data source; this does not seem to work either.

--Keith

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with OpenJPA, but I'm guessing that the `openjpa.jdbc.Schema` property is optional. The datasource (i.e. the one at `jdbc/DataSource`) will dictate the default schema in use.

Have you tried leaving the property out?

Comment: @Keith: OK, and what happened? Help me out, here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use maven.

1-Define profiles for each build scenario in the project pom file or maven settings.

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV Profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <propertis>
                <db-schema>DEVSCHEMA</db-schema>
            </propertis>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>PROD Profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <propertis>
                <db-schema>PRODSCHEMA</db-schema>
            </propertis>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

2- change your persistence.xml as follows:

```
    <persistence>
        <persistence-unit name="persistent-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
                <jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSource</jta-data-source>
                ...
                <properties>
                        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="${db-schema}"/>
                        <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
                        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

3- Put following lines in the project pom file.

```
    <build>        
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just create separate `<persistence-unit>` elements and then dynamically select which one to bind to.
For example:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="DEV_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSource</jta-data-source>
            ...
            <properties>
                    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="DEVSCHEMA"/>
                    <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
                    <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="PROD_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSource</jta-data-source>
            ...
            <properties>
                    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="PRODSCHEMA"/>
                    <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
                    <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set schema name dynamically in the code like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM", schema=Item.SCHEMA)
public class Item implements Serializable {

    public static final String SCHEMA = System.getProperty("env.schema");

    @Id
    @Column (name = "ITEM_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column (name = "ITEM_NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work,  attribute values must be constant :(